# Heroku pushes source code to my repository but not to the platform heroku

Tags: git, heroku

But i have a java application which was created from heroku. I modified it and associated it with a private bitbucket repository.
When i perform a push with the heroku eclipse plugins (commit, then push to upstream) or with a `git push heroku master` command from the directory of my source code on my local machine, it updates my source in my private repository.
 Fine, but when i look at the code deployed on the heroku environment with a `heroku run bash --app myapplication` command i see that my code is not updated.
My code is well associated to my private repository but heroku does not use it to update its source code.
Any ideas what can be wrong ?
Thanks !

Comment: It sounds like your `heroku` remote is actually your BitBucket repository, not Heroku. What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: Git is new for me so i think you're right :                       heroku  https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git (fetch)   
heroku  https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git (push)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `heroku` remote is actually pointed at BitBucket. Here is what I recommend:

1. Rename your existing `heroku` remote to `origin`. This is the traditional name of your "main" remote, but if you prefer you could call it `bitbucket` or something else.

   ```
   git remote rename heroku origin
   ```
2. Now add a new remote called `heroku` that actually points at Heroku.

   ```
   git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:your-repository-name.git
   ```
3. You should now have *two* remotes. If you run `git remote -v` you'll see something like this:

   ```
   heroku  git@heroku.com:your-repository-name.git (fetch)
   heroku  git@heroku.com:your-repository-name.git (push)
   origin  git@bitbucket.org:you/your-repository-name.git (fetch)
   origin  git@bitbucket.org:you/your-repository-name.git (push)
   ```
4. You should now be able to push to Heroku with `git push heroku` and to BitBucket with `git push origin`.